# Add Video Call in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want to create a Hospital App, That app will have the option to visit virtually. I'm planing using Skype API for video call, but i don't know where to start. I can't find any useful documentation to acheive this. Can anyone give me some document or plugin to achieve this on flutter thanks in advance.

Comment: Check https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc

Comment: You can achieve this using platform specific APIs.

Comment: thanks guys this might give me some idea

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang I'm happy to hear, with which approach you achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Check this out: https://videosdk.live/video-calling-api/flutter-android-sdk

Answer (score 6):

Use [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/). It is an Opensource Technology.

Comment: for flutter check following link

https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc

Answer (score 5):

you can have a look on [Agora SDK](https://www.agora.io/en/add-real-time-video-to-your-flutter-apps-using-the-agora-flutter-sdk/) for video Call

Comment: Can we record the voice and save in SD card after finishing the call with this SDK?

Comment: i didn't tried that may we can do (with this or with other plugin while triggering on connect and disconnect )

Comment: no recommended if you planning for a large scale of calls

Comment: @JohnMelodyMelissa yes, you are right, its very expensive

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Jitsi.

[jitsi](https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet)

Comment: This is the best solution because it's completely free.

Comment: @Madhav , yes it is

Comment: This is tutorial for this plugin. https://medium.com/flutter-clan/free-video-conferencing-app-built-on-flutter-62123eddd6e7